# Are there any possibilities to use "goto" inside switch statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, goto

This is my example program in JS. I have to iterate or loop inside the switch statement. So I have used `goto`, but it doesn't working.

Are there any other options to loop this or is my syntax wrong?

```
var input = 1;
switch (input)
{
    case 1: 
        ...
        break;
    case 2: 
        ...
        break;
    case 3: 
        ...
        if (..) { }
        else    
        {
            goto case 2;
        }
        break;
    default: 
        alert("No Return");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Even if this were possible, case 2 was already false, so it will be false again. Explain, specifically, what you are trying to accomplish--i.e. what are you test for true?

Comment: i have added the same goto case 2 in case 1:..But Still not working

Comment: There is no GOTO in JS. Maybe you are looking for case fallthrough: http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/fallthrough.htm

Comment: This code has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there any possibilities to use "goto" inside switch statement in javascript?

No, there are no possibilities to use "goto" inside switch statement, or anywhere else, since JavaScript has no such statement.

To solve your problem, as suggested in a comment, organize your cases (moving 3 above 2) so you can use fall-through:

```
var input = 1;
switch (input)
{
    case 1: 
        ...
        break;
    case 3: 
        ...
        if (..) { ...; break; }
        // fall through to case 2
    case 2: 
        ...
        break;
    default: 
        alert("No Return");
        break;
}
```

In this case, make sure to comment the fall-through so people looking at your code don't think it's a bug. You may also need to add a hint so that your linter does not complain.

Or, just put the logic common to 2 and 3 in a little function:

```
function someLogicFor2Or3() { ... }

    case 2: 
        someLogicFor2OrMaybe3();
        break;
    case 3: 
        ...
        if (..) { }
        else someLogicFor2OrMaybe3();
        break;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following technique to do this :

```
var input = 1;
while (1) {
  switch (input) {
  case 1: 
    ...
    break; // switch

  case 2: 
    ...
    break; // switch

  case 3: 
    ...
    if (..) { }
    else {
      input = 2; // goto case 2;
      continue;  // while
    }
    break; // switch

  default: 
    alert ("No Return");
    break;  // switch
  }
  break;  // while
}
```

Comment: While correct, this method is very hard to parse through and know exactly what is happening for any other developer. The solutions provided by /u/user663031 are much easier to read and are more commonly used.